# Apache Poi Performance issues opening a spreadsheet that is packaged inside a jar

Tags: java, performance, apache-poi

I am trying to open a very small spreadsheet using Apache Poi 3.14.
The spreadsheet is XLSX and has 4 worksheets that only contain shaded column headings with borders (15kB)

I am using the following to access the spreadsheet which is situated in a folder inside my java project (packaged inside the jar when exported).

```
     OPCPackage p = OPCPackage.open(getClass().getResourceAsStream(EXPORT_TEMPLATE));
     XSSFWorkbook wb =  new XSSFWorkbook(p);
```

When I run this in directly from the Eclipse IDE the workbook opens almost instantly, but when I export the application and run the jar it takes 15 seconds to open the workbook.

I'm trying to figure out how I can improve this performance before I add code to create the sheet from scratch.

Comment: After further testing I have found that even creating a workbook from scratch takes just as long so I am not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Are you restricted to using Apache POI 3.14? If not, I wrote a small program earlier that both reads and writes xlsx files, but it uses POI 3.15. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366599/how-to-split-a-excel-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-row-count-using-apache-po/37369058#37369058 Here is the link. I've timed the completion of reading and writing the workbooks at an average of 6 seconds total (without copying formatting). Perhaps that will help.

Comment: I should note, my test workbook had 5000 rows, with 100 columns. 
Only one tab though.

Comment: I tried 3.15 but the issue is still there. I don't understand how it can run so fast inside the development environment, but so slow outside it. Maybe there is something going wrong during the jar creation, but I can't imagine what. This is just creating a blank workbook with Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

Comment: I tried creating an HSSFWorkbook instead and it worked perfectly, but I really need to be using an XLSX spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

The Corporate Antimalware application is impacting on the Workbook Creation process!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there are different Classloader implementations at work inside the IDE and in your application, whereas random access is slowed down a lot outside of Eclipse.

I would test this by extracting the resource completely out of the jar-file into a byte[], e.g. via Commons-IO and only then construct it:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream(EXPORT_TEMPLATE))
XSSFWorkbook wb =  new XSSFWorkbook(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the same result. I get the same issue when I instantiate an empty workbook in memory. I'm sure it is an issue with our anti Malware application. I can see it burning cpu time in the Task Manager when the workbook is being created.